# How to add a Large Binary image as part of a JSON data when testing in POSTMAN?

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy, binary, postman, large-data

### This is my first time storing images as a large-binary with-in Postgres using SQLALCHEMY and I am stumped.

My problem is that I don't know the formatting of how to send the large binary. It is a string format or an array format?

**See below for what I am testing.**

[image: POSTMAN JSON DATA]

```
{
   "user_data": {"password":"123abc",
                "name":"Tommy",
                "city":"New York",
                "occupation":"Fashion stylist", 
                "subscription": "gold",
                "email":"tjnyc@aol.com",
                "secret":"appples_over",
                "profileImg":["0b1101000", "0b1100101", "0b1101100", "0b1101100", "0b1101111", "0b100000", "0b1110111", "0b1101111", "0b1110010", "0b1101100", "0b1100100"]
                }
}
```

**When testing in postman I get this error exception in my terminal.**

> Error Message:  can't escape list to binary

**Here are my columns in my sqlalchemy ORM.**
[image: ORM]

Answer (score 1):

Don't do that.

Use a proper normalized data model instead of JSON. The table should have a column of type `bytea` where you store the image in binary form.

If the image is really big, storing it in the database is questionable: [performance is not as good](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/binary-data-performance-in-postgresql/), and large databases are a headache for backup and other maintenance operations.